org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate void using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
I am using spring data mongo for updating one property by the id using mongo repository methods
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<CategoryEntity,Integer> {
  @Query("{'id' : ?0}, {$set: {'count' : ?1}}")
  void updateCountById(Integer id, Integer count);
}

Getting following exception while calling this function
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate void using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:344)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:250)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ProjectingReadCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3186)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2788)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2542)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:127)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$4(AbstractMongoQuery.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.updatePriorityById(Unknown Source)   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)


Please use code tags next time when posting stacktraces instead of quote tags. Using the proper tags ensures the stacktrace is still readable.

You are using MongoDB and @Query is used for data retrieval. To do an update use the @Update. As also explained in the documentation.
public interface CategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<CategoryEntity,Integer> {
  @Update("{'id' : ?0}, {$set: {'count' : ?1}}")
  void updateCountById(Integer id, Integer count);
}

TIP: You don't need the @Repository for Spring Data repositories, saves you a line of code (and it won't hurt your head as much ;) ).

I am using 3.0.2.RELEASE version of spring data mongo db where we can't use update annotation and i can't upgrade to latest version. just want a workaround for this.

If you want that you might want to include such information in your question as that is quite crucial. Also are you really using 3.0.2 or are you on Spring Boot 3.0.2 and use the starter as those are quite different things!
